# CSS in GTK+ doesn't work

Tags: css, c, gtk, gtk3

```
GtkCssProvider *provider;
GdkDisplay *display;
GdkScreen *screen;

provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
display = gdk_display_get_default ();
screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

const gchar *myCssFile = "style.css";
GError *error = 0;

gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(provider, g_file_new_for_path(myCssFile), &error);
g_object_unref (provider);
```

This doesn't work, but when I change "style.css" to the full path, everything works great. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"This doesn't work"* This is not a helpful problem description.

Comment: Indeed. Which Gtk+ version are you using? It's important to know due to CSS changes between versions. Did you try Gtk Inspector? It let's you tweak CSS at runtime.

Comment: version 3.22.26. "This doesn't work" I mean colors didn't change. When I use full path, everything from css file work.

Comment: It sounds as if the CSS file is not in the current directory of the process, which is why it works with the full path.

Comment: I copied and pasted it everywhere and it still won't work :D

Comment: Is the binary in the same path as style.css?

Comment: Have you looked at the last argument of `gtk_css_provider_load_from_file`? That amazing thing is where the error code and message is stored if that function call fails. So what if you gave an eye to what is in that error and printed the error message? Don't you think it would be easier for everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, do the bare minimum: check your error codes, and process them.

```
const gchar *css_relpath = "style.css";
GError *error = NULL;
GFile *css_file = g_file_new_for_path(css_relpath); 

gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(provider, css_file, &error);
if (error)
{
    // Display a warning if the stylesheet is not loaded
    g_warning ("%s", error->message);

    // Free the memory allocated for the error
    // and acknowledge the error has been processed
    g_clear_error (&error);
}
g_object_unref (css_file);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, on Mac OS with GTK 3.22.26 everything works now, but on Linux with GTK 3.18 I got error: "style.css:2:19Not a valid image". What does it mean?

Comment: Your css file has an error at line 2, character 19. From the file content you posted, your css file is probably badly formed. I'm not familiar with CSS3, are you sure `image()` is allowed? Wherever I look I see `url()` instead.

Comment: Ok, didn't see at first the different GTK+ versions. There has been changes in the CSS engine, so different versions may behave differently. `background-image` on GTK+ 3.18 is documented as `background-image: [none|url|linear-gradient]`, so I don't think using `image()` would work on that version. See https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.18/GtkCssProvider.html

Answer (score 0):

```
window {
    background-image: image(Peru);
}

button {
    background-image: image(Tan);
    background-color: Tan;
}

button:active {
    background-image: image(#C69F6C);
    background-color: #C69F6C;
}

#unpressed {
    background-image: image(Sienna);
    background-color: Sienna;
}

#button_black {
    background-image: image(Black);
    background-color: Black;
}

#button_white {
    background-image: image(White);
    background-color: White;
}
```

"style.css:2:19Not a valid image"
My .css file above